# TradingView Alerts Script

Tags: pine-script

Does anyone know how can I create a TradingView Pine script that will trigger an alert on any stock in my watchlist, when the stock price reaches/crosses the Supply/Demand areas of a stock?

Thanks!

Tried to create a script using chatGPT but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Pinescript has no access to your watch list. You are looking for a screener but it is not so easy to implement and there definitely some limitaions.

You should be using the `request.security()` function to get data from other tickers. This way you can implement a "screener". However, one script can only have 40 `security()` calls. So, you can only scan 40 tickers (best case scenario - could be less) with on script.

Check out [Other timeframes and data](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Other_timeframes_and_data.html#other-timeframes-and-data).